# window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission not working in other computers

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

See the following JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RequestPermission (callback) {
    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(callback);
    }

function getMonitor(title,msg) {
    if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() > 0) {
        RequestPermission(getMonitor);
        } else {
        var popup = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('',title,msg);
        popup.show();
        setTimeout(function(){popup.cancel();}, '10000');
        }
    }
</script>
```

in a new computers that I open this code, for some reason he didn't alert the permission, in my first computer when I clicked on some button on other website and clicked on "Allow" button, all the alerts are working.

any advice?

Comment: Compare versions of the browsers, on that and this computer. Check, that on this computer (and browser) `webkitNotifications` is available.

Comment: this is what im getting on consol: Notifications are supported!
but no notification shown

Answer (score -1):

Since only know that when the user has authorized it returns zero.

Change

```
window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() > 0
```

to

```
window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() != 0
```

and try.

**Edit:**

After working for a months, I have realized that *window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission()* will work only on called from user events like click/mousehover/gesture, it will not work it called directly from javascript. So call *getMonitor* function on user event. Read [Chromium docs](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) (section requestPermission for further info)